# Batch file to Stop/Start a Website in IIS 6.0

Tags: iis, deployment, iis-6, iisreset

I an IIS reset each time after we do deployments using a batch file that does the following

```
IISRESET.EXE SERVER01 /RESTART
```

However, this is now a problem since we are currently hosting other website instances in the same IIS in SERVER01. My question is, is it possible to just do a quick refresh/restart of a single site instance from IIS? How do I achieve this? Also, is it going to have the same effect as restarting the entire IIS?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check this out - You can restart a single Site only: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772200%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: I'm sorry but I forgot to mention but we are still using IIS 6.0. Is there anything you think could help me achieve the same restart of a single site? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check this out: https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/17ee85c0-9248-4381-b90f-877c028c1c7e.mspx?mfr=true